# How to invoke a function on unpausing the tree?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Is it possible to invoke a function or connect a signal when the tree is unpaused?

for example I have this setup:
[image]

the world script:

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    get_tree().paused=true
    
    # do something
    
    get_tree().paused=false
```

the thing script:

```
extends Node2D

func _unpaused():
    # reset something when the tree is unpaused
```

is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I can't find a signal or virtual method for that.

I'd say use an autoload that controls `paused`, and make sure everything on the projects that needs `paused` goes through the autoload. So the autoload can do whatever you need when it changes.